# Sharing car with provisional licence holder. Is it necessary to remove L plates when qualified driver is driving?

Tags: united-kingdom, driving

My partner is learning to drive. She's brought a car ready for when she passes her test, hopefully in a couple weeks. Her insurance is aware that she -- the main driver -- has a provisional licence, and I am a named driver on her policy with a full licence.

She is having lessons with a professional instructor, but I have been supervising her on occasion as I meet the [requirements](https://www.gov.uk/driving-lessons-learning-to-drive/practising-with-family-or-friends):

- I am older than 21.
- Have a licence for that category of vehicle.
- Had that licence for more than 3 years.

We have L plates shown on her car. She wanted to drive to her work, with me supervising, and then I drive the car home alone.

My question is: Would I be committing an offence by driving her car back home, by myself, with the L plates still showing?

As far as I can tell, it's at the very least advisable to remove them, but not illegal. I do not wish to waste police time, but I would expect an officer to pull me over and investigate why I'm driving alone with L plates.

Sadly I can't just remove the L plates since they're stickers. They won't go back on if I pull them off. Hence my question.

As a side note: I will not be using a motorway when driving alone. Obviously we cannot use the motorway when I am supervising her.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Highway Code said:

> Vehicles. Any vehicle driven by a learner MUST display red L plates.
>   In Wales, either red D plates, red L plates, or both, can be used.
>   Plates MUST conform to legal specifications and MUST be clearly
>   visible to others from in front of the vehicle and from behind. Plates
>   should be removed or covered when not being driven by a learner
>   (except on driving school vehicles). [Law MV(DL)R reg 16 & sched 4]

The good old Highway Code "Must" vs "Should". "Must" means that it is a legal issue, anything that is "Should" is only advisory

Comment: Perfect. My logic was that I've not seen professional instructors remove their L plates when driving to their next student. But I wasn't sure if they were exempt.